# Sketch Fourier Transform Analysis Equation

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions, fourier-transform

First of all,thank you for your attention.

The exercise is very straightforward and it's easy to understand what is asking.

I basically have two functions. I calculated (correctly) the fourier transform of each one.

Now I need to sketch one period of the magnitude of each Fourier transform.

$$e^-j\omega * \frac{1}{1 - (1/2)e^-j\omega}$$

$$\frac{0.75e^-j\omega}{1.25-cos(\omega)}$$

Thanks once again,

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please [do not use image for the critical part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) of the question. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: Thanks.

The problem is solved now.